# How do I get Wicd to use other drivers in Debian 7.2 Xfce?

Tags: debian, arch-linux, drivers, networkmanager, xubuntu

I have an old laptop with Debian Xfce 7.2 with a wireless-n pcmcia card. NetworkManager and Wicd have the same issues with Wi-Fi, especially with authentication.

The card works perfect on Ubuntu distros (though Ubuntu distros are too slow on this old laptop).

I saw [a post on Google+](https://plus.google.com/107988923652678124819/posts/VkzsMp626sw) where a guy copied a `/lib/firmware` from Arch Linux to his Debian machine and his Wi-Fi problems stopped.

I tried the same thing except from Xubuntu to Debian, but it didn't work.

Any way to make this work?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? If the problem is related to authentication, which you mention in the question, you should really add more details about how exactly does it not work, if it shows an error message then what does the message say and so.

Comment: doesnt show an error message, just quits.

Comment: So when you try to connect to Wi-Fi network with networkmanager or wicd, the program just quits? Would you like to show us the output of both of the following commands (run the following commands on terminal): `wicd`, `nm-applet`. Those commands should open the GUI of networkmanager and wicd: just try to connect there to the network, and when the program quits, the terminal should have some kind of error message.